# Why was my comment removed?

Tags: discussion

On this question: [What causes pollution when cooking?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/113359/what-causes-pollution-when-cooking)

Could whoever removed it elaborate on the reason why? Perhaps then I can post better comments in the future.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't remove it, but I can look at the comment and the history - it was flagged, and the flag was validated by another mod. I don't think either of them needs to personally explain, since there's nothing mysterious here.

The removed comment was hostile toward another user, with a clear frustrated and/or angry tone. There's really not much more to say than that; I'm not going to bother dissecting it. That kind of behavior isn't welcome here.

If you'd like to write better comments in the future, I'd suggest:

- Read the [code of conduct](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/conduct).
- If you're feeling angry or any other negative emotion, take a breather before you write a comment. Be especially careful if you're angry with a person you're speaking to.
- When writing a comment, ask yourself what your goal is. If it's something other than working with other users to improve posts, maybe just don't post it. If you do have that constructive goal, consider whether your comment is likely to accomplish it, and how others are likely to react to your comment.

Comment: The other person's comment is clearly not constructive either. I can't see my own comment anymore for some reason so I don't know what it says exactly, I do remember toning it down, probably not enough then. Still feels weird that someone comments "I wish I could remove this from the site" and then flags a comment going "erm why would you even bother saying that, very helpful"

Comment: @Luc If you think someone's comment isn't constructive, flag it and move on. And the person who flagged your comment wasn't the other person who commented on the question, though if it had been, it still would have been correct to delete yours - it was absolutely *way* over the line, way beyond just "not constructive".